# angular 2, how to write custom mousedown/touchstart implementation

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to support both, mouse and touch events, so I have code like this

```
 <button
        (touchstart)="doSomething($event)"
        (mousedown)="doSomething($event)">
```

Is there some way to merge both into one ? I also noticed that touch devices trigger mouse events, so I need a better solution. Is it possible, for example, to write an event listener, something like this

```
<button (pointerDown)="doSomething">...</button>
```

And in my PointerDown event class I listen to both events ? This would be nice :)

I also found [ng2-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-events) library, not sure if it will do what I need.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all that using attribute directive and @HostListener. Dont have everything in my head but you'll understand once you look into it

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean you have to also add the attribute too, like: `<button my-custom-events (pointerDown)="doSomething($event)">..`?

Comment: Yes something in the line with `@Output pointerDown = new EventEmitter()` and `pointerDown.emit(value)` should make call to the callback you provided

Comment: Yes, I did that. For those interested, [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) is the documentation I used to figure it out